# Use java script to redirect to new url

Tags: javascript, redirect, indexof

I cannot use htaccess. I need to use something like

"if(document.location.href.indexOf('**/m/**') > -1)"

to redirect from xxx.com/**m**/xxx/xxx.html to **m**.xxx.com/xxx/xxx.html.

I need to it to work for all url's that contain /m/.

EXAMPLE: example.com/**m**/folder1/article1.html

REDIRECT TO: **m**.example.com/folder1/article1.html

Thank you for any help.

Comment: use ```window.location = yoururl;``` [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location). Similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like as follows:

```
if (window.location.pathname.startsWith('/m/')) {
  var redirectTo = window.location.protocol 
    + '//m.' 
    + window.location.host 
    + window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/m/, '');
  window.location.replace(redirectTo);
}
```

Comment: Awesome!. Is there an edit for this code to not look at .protocol or change .protocol to :http:// NOT https:// ? Thanks.

Comment: @Joelsmith Yes, sure, you can simply replace `window.location.protocol` with `"http:"` string

Comment: Great ! Perfect ! Just what i needed. Thank you soooo much.

Comment: My pleasure! Please accept the answer if you find it helpful, thanks!